# Pandas iterate over each row of a column and change its value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
   Name  Age
0   tom   10
1  nick   15
2  juli   14
```

I am trying to iterate over each name --> connect to a mysql database --> match the name with a column in the database --> fetch the id for the name --> and replace the id in the place of name

in the above data frame.  The desired output is as follows:

```
   Name  Age
0   1    10
1   2    15
2   4    14
```

The following is the code that I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:Abc@123def@localhost/aivu")

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
print(df)

for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    cquery="select id from students where studentsName="+'"' + rows['Name'] + '"'
    sid = pd.read_sql(cquery, con=engine)
    df['Name'] = sid['id'].iloc[0]
    print(df[['Name','Age')
```

The above code prints the following output:

```
   Name  Age
0   1    10
1   1    15
2   1    14
   Name  Age
0   2    10
1   2    15
2   2    14
   Name  Age
0   4    10
1   4    15
2   4    14
```

I understand it iterates through the entire table for each matched name and prints it.  How do you get the value replaced only once.

Comment: try `df.loc[index, 'Name'] = sid['id'].iloc[0]` instead. Your current solution is overwriting that whole column - not the individual row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code as written is the line:

```py
df['Name'] = sid['id'].iloc[0]
```

This sets *every value* in the `Name` column to the first `id` entry in your query result.

To accomplish what you want, you want something like:

```py
df.loc[index, 'Name'] = sid['id'].iloc[0]
```

This will set the value at index location `index` in column `name` to the first `id` entry in your query result.

This will accomplish what you want to do, and you can stop reading here if you're in a hurry. If you're *not* in a hurry, and you'd like to become wiser, I encourage you to read on.

It is generally a mistake to loop over the rows in a dataframe. It's also generally a mistake to iterate through a list carrying out a single query on each item in the list. Both of these are slow and error-prone.

A more idiomatic (and faster) way of doing this would be to get all the relevant rows from the database in one query, merge them with your current dataframe, and then drop the column you no longer want. Something like the following:

```py
names = df['Name'].tolist()
query = f"select id, studentsName as Name where name in({','.join(names)})"
student_ids = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
df_2 = df.merge(student_ids, on='Name', how='left')
df_with_ids = df_2[['id', 'Age']]
```

One query executed, no loops to worry about. Let the database engine and Pandas do the work for you.

Comment: thank you...your earlier suggestion helped me.  I will try the other suggestion as well.

Answer (score 2):

Slight rewrite of your code, if you want to do a transformation in general on a dataframe this is a better way to go about it

```py
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:Abc@123def@localhost/aivu")

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])

def replace_name(name: str) -> int:
    cquery="select id from students where studentsName='{}'".format(student_name)
    sid = pd.read_sql(cquery, con=engine)
    return sid['id'].iloc[0]

df[Name] = df[Name].apply(lambda x: replace_name(x.value))
```

This should perform the transformation you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can do this kind of operations the following way, please follow comments and feel free to ask questions:

```
import pandas as pd

# create frame
x = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["A", "B", "C"],
        "age": [1, 2, 3]
     }
)

# create some kind of db
mock_database = {"A": 10, "B": 20, "C": 30}

x["id"] = None  # add empty column

print(x)

# change values in the new column
for i in range(len(x["name"])):
    x["id"][i] = mock_database.get(x["name"][i])

print("*" * 100)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do that would be :

```py
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://root:Abc@123def@localhost/aivu")

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
print(df)

name_ids = []
for student_name in df['Name']:
    cquery="select id from students where studentsName='{}'".format(student_name)
    sid = pd.read_sql(cquery, con=engine)
    name_ids.append(sid if sid is not None else None )

# DEBUGED WITH name_ids = [1,2,3]
df['Name'] = name_ids
print(df)
```

I checked with an example list of ids and it works , I guess if the query format is correct this will work. 
Performance-wise I could not think a better solution , since you will have to do a lot of queries (one for each student) but there probably is some way to get all the ids with less queries.